# How to specify Display Name in Gmail SMTP?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

An example would better explain my problem:
If 'Mark Jones' owns xyz@gmail.com and sends a mail to a person through the traditional method(Compose), the reciever gets a mail titled as 'Mark Jones' followed by the subject. But the same mail sent through Gmail SMTP is titled as 'xyz' followed by the subject. 
I am using javax.mail library for the SMTP. And I want 'Mark Jones' to be displayed instead of 'xyz' even when I am sending through Java SMTP. Is there any way of achiving this?
Following is the code I am currently using:

```
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtps.user", "xyz@gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtps.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtps.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("xyz@gmail.com", "password");
        }
    });
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        msg.setSubject(this.subject);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(this.to));
        msg.setText(this.body);
        try (Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps")) {
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", Integer.valueOf("465"), "Mark Jones", "password");
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        }
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried **Mark Jones<xyz@gmail.com>** in your `setFrom`?

Comment: Use the [InternetAddress constructor that allows you to specifiy both the email address and the personal name](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).  You can also clean up some of these [common mistakes](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ.html#commonmistakes) while you're in there and simplify your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon) suggested, the following code did the trick

```
try{ 
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com","Mark Jones")); 
}catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```